# Bootstrap footer - Changing from 6 columns to 2 columns in small display

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my code:

```
<div class="row clearfix">
<div class="col-md-3 column"> </div>
<div class="col-md-1 column">
  <p>Solution 1</p>
  <p>Solution 2</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1 column">
  <p>Solution 3</p>
  <p>Solution 4</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1 column">
  <p>Solution 5</p>
  <p>Solution 6</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1 column">
  <p>About us</p>
  <p>References</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1 column">
  <p>Contact us</p>
  <p>Guide</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-1 column">
  <p>ToS</p>
  <p>Imprint</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 column"> </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/RZiyxudqnS

On bigger displays I want 6 groups of two links. (6 columns)

On smaller display I want 2 groups with 6 links. (2 columns)

But when I make the display smaller, they all change into a linear layout with only one column.

How can I set it up to have 2 columns?

Right now I am using a 3-1-1-1-1-1-1-3 layout.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `col-xs-6` for smaller devices

```
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-3 column"> </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-6">
      <p>Solution 1</p>
      <p>Solution 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-6">
      <p>Solution 3</p>
      <p>Solution 4</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-6">
      <p>Solution 5</p>
      <p>Solution 6</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-6">
      <p>About us</p>
      <p>References</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-6">
      <p>Contact us</p>
      <p>Guide</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-6">
      <p>ToS</p>
      <p>Imprint</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 column"> </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap there are four classes
`.col-lg-` 
`.col-md-` 
`.col-sm-` 
`.col-xs-`
This diffirent classes works on different screen sizes

```
.col-xs-X  **0 < X < 767px;** 

.col-sm-X **768px < X < 991px;**

.col-sm-X **992px < X < 1169px;**

.col-sm-X **1170px < X**
```

This is the link for Bootstrap Grid System. [**Click Here**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)